# How can I add "format" for the piece of the code which is given below?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
   zip(a,b,c,d)
   with open('output.dat', 'w') as f:
   print >>f, ("%-25s %-25s %-25s %s" %(x, y, z, k))
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
   writer.writerows(zip(a,b,c,d))
```

The outputs of this code are like

```
51715.505899065996  2724172.4436709681  3081070.212397085   3419080.1274145059
```

I want to write these numbers in the form of exponent and round up e.g. for the first output

```
5.172E4 ........
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the scientific notation format, something like this:

```
num = 51715.505899065996
# .3 to keep 3 digit in fractional part
print('%.3e' % num)
print('{:.3e}'.format(num))
# 5.172e+04
```

for your scenario, you can use format by map, I treat `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` as list, I don't know whether I got misunderstanding for this:

```
a = [51715.505899065996, 2724172.4436]
b = [2724172.4436709681, 81070.2123]
c = [3081070.212397085, 715.50589906599]
d = [3419080.1274145059, 9080.12741450]
zip(a,b,c,d)
with open('output.dat', 'w') as f:
    # print >>f, ("%-25s %-25s %-25s %s" %(x, y, z, k))
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for A, B, C, D in zip(a,b,c,d):
        writer.writerow(map(lambda x:'{:.3e}'.format(x), (A,B,C,D)))
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: you defined num=51715.505 and print it with format, I think this can not add directly in the code above or is it possible?

Comment: it can add to your code, and I will modify it for you, but you need to give me more code, such as what's the type of a, b, c, d? are they list? @Ttys

Comment: @Ttys I have added `format` to your code, hope that is what you need

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. It worked. print >>f, ("%-25s %-25s %-25s %s" %(x, y, z, k)) are my headers. no need to deactivate them.

Comment: glad to hear about it, accept my answer if it helps you : )

Answer (score 2):

`print('%.xe' % y)` or `print('{:.xe}'.format(y)` will print a number `y` in scientific notation, with a decimal precision of `x` places

For example, `print('%.2e' % 12)` will print `1.20e+.01`